# Add role to a user discord.py

Tags: python

i want to add a role when a person join my discord so i don't know what don't working here.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    pseudo = member.mention
    print(member)

    print("New member connected")
    # Envoyer un message privé au nouveau membre

    await member.send(f"Bienvenue sur CodeNet {pseudo} \n Fait la commande !!regles pour lire les règles ! \n Notre site web: http://codenet.ddns.net/")
    channel = bot.get_channel(771466599369539584)
    await channel.send(f"Bienvenue {pseudo} sur CodeNet !!!")
    test = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="membre")
    await member.add_roles(member, test)
```

Here the error

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Mick/PycharmProjects/lexigreybot/main.py", line 31, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(member, test)
  File "C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 664, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 243, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

Comment: Could you described what you tested, what error did you get and a minimal setup to reproduce the error ?

Comment: hello, when a person connect to my discord, the bot add a role to the person. Here the error.

Comment: First, you should check that member is not None since discord.utils.get returns None if no element can be found